# Convert pem to key, SSL virtual host apache redhat aws

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, virtualhost

There are a lot of reference for converting a key to pem but not the other way around.
I [followed these steps](http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2013/09/21/geotrust-rapidssl-amazon-aws-elb.html) to create a `.pem` key for AWS load balancer.
The top of the cert looks like

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now i have to use that to configure apache virtual domains and I need a `.key` format which should look like so:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/public.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/mykey.key #<<<<<
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

**my question** is how do i go about converting a `pem` to a `key`?
something like:
`openssl rsa -in /etc/pki/tls/certs/mykey.pem -outform ???`

note,  i saw something like this `openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der`  but `.der` and `.key` is the same?

Comment: Former Stack Overflow question: http://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Openssl pkcs8 default format gives RSA PRIVATE KEY](https://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key) (migrated from Stack Overflow):

> Perform  pkcs8 with -topk8 to convert this key from traditional format to pkcs#8 format.

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform pem -in file.key -outform pem -nocrypt -out file.pem
```

Above, *traditional* format is `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, and *PKCS8* format is `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.