# How do I provide correctly formatted certificate files to AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I'm trying to setup SSL for a custom domain on appengine. The app is presently working fine with http on the custom domain.

My certificate provider asked me to use openssl to do the following:

`openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout newkey.key -out newcsr.csr`

This produced two new files, a .key and a .csr

I used the .csr in the process of creating the certificate and I have seen references to comodo so I am presuming they have provided the signing. My provider now gives me the option to download the certificate and an intermediate certificate. When I download the certificate, it is saved as a .crt file by Google Chrome.

The .key file begins with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`

The .crt file begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

AppEngine requires a cert file and a key file. I have tried two upload the .crt file and the .key file but no slots are used.

I have tried to convert the .crt to a PEM with:

`openssl x509 -in certificate-xxxxx.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM`

That gives me a .pem but that also fails to be accepted.

I'd appreciate any comments as not being a security expert I am flying blind here.

UPDATE -----

It seems that both my certificate and key file ARE in .pem format.

I thought that there was an issue with the key file since it began with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- rather than -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- but I was being led astray by older pages - see https://www.globalsign.com/blog/ssl-with-google-app-engine.html.

It seems the difference is just *traditional* format rather than *PKCS8* format - see [Convert pem to key, SSL virtual host apache redhat aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645526/convert-pem-to-key-ssl-virtual-host-apache-redhat-aws)

Interestingly, now when loading my cert file and key file, I get an error of 'Both the private key and SSL certificate should be in unencrypted PEM format'. I am wondering whether the issue is to to with being encrypted or whether as the certificate provider was not Comodo that I need to incorporate an interim certificate as well somehow.

RESOLVED ----
The key file was in PEM format but not RSA. I used:

`openssl rsa -in newkey.key -out newkey.pem`

and the files are now accepted by Google.

The newkey.pem file starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- so clearly you need this for it to be accepted by Google.

Comment: "I have tried to convert the .crt to a PEM with ..." - the certificate and key file are already in PEM. That's what the `-----BEGIN ... -----` and `-----END ... -----` are.

Comment: You know, you never told us what the error is. At over 1000 points, you should know better ;)

Comment: There was no error message. I select the two files required in the Google Admin SSL page, then click on Upload.The file references disappear and nothing else changes and I see no slots used. I have tried to be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: This might help: [Logging Events in Your Application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging). It discusses accessing the application logs from the admin console.

Answer (score 1):

I followed a similar approach and succeeded.

The difference is my key file begins with:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I used this line to generate the key and csr:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out mydomain.com.csr -keyout mydomain.com.key -subj "/C=FR/ST=Essonne/L=Paris/O=MyCompany/CN=mydomain.com"
```

I suppose you tried to import it on ? :
[https://admin.google.com/yourdomain.com/AdminHome?fral=1#SecuritySettings:flyout=ssl](https://admin.google.com/yourdomain.com/AdminHome?fral=1#SecuritySettings%3aflyout=ssl)

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I think the key I originally generated is not an RSA key and thus the header difference. I will step thru the SSL process again..

Comment: *If* you need `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, then you need to use `openssl pkcs8 ...`. That will get you the additional `RSA` in `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. See [Convert pem to key, SSL virtual host apache redhat aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645526/convert-pem-to-key-ssl-virtual-host-apache-redhat-aws).